# Will FPGA synthesis tools ignore unused modules?

Tags: fpga, verilog, vhdl, vivado, synthesis

In a VHDL/Verilog design, is it a bad practice to define several (related) modules in the same file?

Will the Vivado synthesis tool be 'smart' enough to not book FPGA resources for unused modules?

Comment: What does your experiment reveal? Just try it!

Comment: In general, the netlist generator will ignore any module that isn't actually instantiated anywhere in the hierarchy defined by the top-level module. Furthermore, the optimization phase of synthesis will "chew away" any logic (even logic within a module) whose inputs or outputs don't go anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike software where the compiler will sometimes keep code around that isn't actually called (particularly for things like libraries), this isn't the case for HDL designs.  This is because HDL isn't "executed" like software, instead it gets converted to a netlist, which defines components and the connections between them.  So an HDL *module* never consumes any resources.  What does consume resources are *instances*.  A module that is never instantiated simply does not exist in the synthesized design and hence consumes no resources.  Similarly, if you have multiple instances of the same module, each instance will consume more resources.  For example, four instances of one module will consume four times the logic resources of one instance (ignoring optimizations, etc.).

Additionally, the tools will take steps to optimize the design and remove unnecessary logic.  Inputs that are tied off to constant values will be removed through "constant propagation", which will simplify logic to remove any connections whose value can be determined to be constant during synthesis.  Similarly, outputs that do not drive anything are removed.  Also, identical logic with identical inputs will also be merged.

Comment: " Similarly, outputs that do not drive anything are removed".  It goes further than that.  All the logic/registers behind that output are removed also, unless and intermediate result (signal) is used internally.

Comment: Not really.  The optimization steps are simply repeated until there is nothing left to optimize.  For example, a constant input will result in the gate it drives being swapped to something with the corresponding equivalent functionality.  If that was the only input, then the gate will be removed completely, and all downstream inputs will be replaced by the corresponding constants.  Repeat until there are no constant inputs.  Same for unused outputs, if a gate has no fanout, delete it.  Repeat until there are no unused outputs.

Answer (score 4):

Vivado has a specific property `top` that you can use to set the top-level module. From there, the elaboration process looks recursively down the hierarchy collecting required modules to complete the design. Any module compiled but not instantiated is ignored.

I believe there are a number of other mechanisms used to figure out which modules to include in the simulation or synthesis environment.